# React functional component doesnt re-run firebase query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a database request working for my functional component. The issue is the code only runs once and the database query doesn't update. When the user settings are changed, this screen doesn't update to reflect the changes. How can you get this behavior to work properly?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, forceUpdate } from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";

import Button from './Button'
import Background from './Background'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { storage, store } from "../App.js";

export default function Dashboard(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const user = props.route.params.user
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [about, setAbout] = useState('');
  const [interests, setInterests] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');

    console.log("TEST")
    var docRef = store.collection('users').doc(props.route.params.user.uid)
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("DOC Dash", doc.data())
        setName(doc.data().name);
        setInterests(doc.data().interests);
        setAbout(doc.data().about);
        setImage(doc.data().photoURL)
        setLocation(doc.data().location)
      }
    });

  return (
    <Background>
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Navbar />
      <View style={styles.info}>
        <Image source={{uri: image}} style={styles.image} />
        <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
        <View style={styles.details}>
          <Text>{location}</Text>
          <Text>{about}</Text>
          <Text>Interests: {interests}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </Background>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is getting realtime updates. [Firestore realtime updates doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-v8)

The query should look something like this

```
store.collection('users').doc(props.route.params.user.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
 console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
})
```

Comment: This worked. It's just confusing because another implementation of that code also worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

To get realtime updates when the data changes, use `onSnapshot` instead of `get`:

```
docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).